# How to get End date of last 12 months in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need a query where i can get last 12 month's end date  from the present system date in oracle .

Below is the sample query i am using in Oracle

```
select
  trunc(add_months(sysdate,level-1),'MM') first_day,
  last_day(add_months(sysdate,level-1)) last_day
  from dual
connect by level<=12;
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query? As i can see it solve the task, dotsn't it?

Comment: This query is giving me 12 months from now to future . But i need for the past 12 months.

Comment: Just make your level -1 a negative number.  
select
  trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1*(level-1)),'MM') first_day,
  last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1*(level-1))) last_day
  from dual
connect by level<=12;

Comment: Unless you truncate the second expression too, last_day will include the current time from sysdate; for example first_day 2015-04-01 00:00:00 and last_day 2015-04-30 09:43:24. Unless your NLS_DATE_FORMAT shows the time that won't be obvious, and might cause confusion. Just something to be aware of whichever answer you go with.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
      trunc(add_months(sysdate-numtoyminterval(1, 'YEAR'),level-1),'MM')  first_day, 
      last_day(add_months(sysdate-numtoyminterval(1, 'YEAR'),level-1)) last_day 
from dual 
connect by level<=12;
```

Instead to start now i.e. `sysdate`, the start will be one year ago: `sysdate-numtoyminterval(1, 'YEAR')`

Comment: That calculation will fail if run on a leap day - as there is no Feb 29th in the previous year. You can see that with `select date '2012-02-29' - numtoyminterval(1, 'YEAR') from dual`. And at the moment the last_day is keeping the current time, which you probably don't really want, but I see the OP's does that too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
    SELECT   TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -(LEVEL - 1)), 'MM') FIRST_DAY,
             LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -(LEVEL - 1))) LAST_DAY
      FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY   LEVEL <= 12;
```

Comment: The last_day is keeping the current time, from sysdate, which you probably don't really want; though the OP's version does that too.

Comment: With TRUNC the author of the question can simply solve.

Comment: Oh yes, just pointing it out for the OP's benefit, as it isn't going to be obvious unless the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is showing the time, and might cause odd effects. Maybe I should have commented on the question instead, come to think of it!